# Error "no such table CUSTOMERS" when trying to connect to Windows Azure SQL database with Delphi FireDac

Tags: sql, delphi, azure, firedac

I am new to remote database connections and I want to setup a very simple single table Delphi XE6 project to view a table ('CUSTOMERS') that I've just created in a small Windows Azure SQL database. I plan to use this access for both VCL code and FireMonkey on Android later. I can see and edit the table using the Azure dashboard.

To test the VCL code, i've dropped an FDConnection on my form with a TFDTable, TDatasource and TDBGrid. I've seen example connection info [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connect_to_Microsoft_SQL_Server_(FireDAC)) but this refers to the MSSQL driver which I presume that I don't have because I'm using XE6 Professional. So I've used a TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink and tried using the SQLite driver with connection params:

```
User_Name=user@56ss8sbeq
Database=tcp:56ss8sbeq.database.windows.net
Password=1234
Encrypt=Yes
MetaDefCatalog=DB123SQL
DriverID=SQLite
```

My table is CUSTOMERS and this is in the table name property of the TFDTable. When I run the project I get no connection errors but I do get "[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR@ no such table CUSTOMERS". Does this indicate that I'm being stupid in trying to use that driver? If so, do I have any way of accessing my DB with FireDAC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK *Windows Azure SQL database* is a MS SQL database hosted on the cloud.

You need an MS SQL driver. You just can not link to MS SQL with a SQLite3 driver!

Upgrade your XE6 edition by buying the FireDAC bundle, or switch to other libraries, like [ADO Components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Working_with_ADO_Components), which are part of XE6 Professional if I remember well.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, I did not realise that a FireDac-only upgrade was possible. I will probably go that route.